# HTML FileReader

Tags: html, filereader

```
function fileSelected() {
    // get selected file element
    var files = document.getElementById('files[]').files;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++)  //for multiple files          
    {
        (function (file) {
            var fileObj = {
                Size: bytesToSize(file.size),
                Type: file.type,
                Name: file.name,
                Data: null
            };

            var reader = new window.FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                fileObj.Data = e.target.result;
            };
            // read selected file as DataURL
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);

           //Create Item
           CreateFileUploadItem(fileObj);

        })(files[i]);
   }
}

function CreateFileUploadItem (item) {
    console.log(item);

    $('<li>', {
        "class": item.Type,
        "data-file": item.Data,
        "html": item.Name + ' ' + item.Size
    }).appendTo($('#filesForUpload'));
}
```

So when console.log(item) gets run in the CreateFileUploadItem function it shows the item.Data. YET it won't add it to the data-file of the LI. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `readAsDataURL` is asynchronous. Thus, the function call is likely returning prior to the `onload` function being called. So, the value of `fileObj.Data` is still null when you are attempting to use it in `CreateFileUploadItem`.

To fix it, you should move the call to `CreateFileUploadItem` into your `onload` function. As for the console logging the proper value, you can't rely on that being synchronous either. I think using a breakpoint during debugging at that line instead will likely show the true null value.